# how to get MAC aaddress and Modified date of text file in C++ builders

Tags: c++, c++builder

how to get mac address of pc and modified date of text file in runtime program,using C++ builder,if both matches red color rectangle should come,or else green colour...as an output

Comment: A MAC address and a modification date will never match...

Comment: Please add more information.  Something that would really help would be concrete examples of what you would expect to match, and what you wouldn't expect to match

Comment: Please make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

For the MAC address, look at the Win32 API `GetAdapterAddresses()` and similar functions.  Keep in mind that a PC can have multiple MACs available, one for each installed network adapter if the PC is connected to multiple networks.

For the file date, look at the Win32 API `GetFileTime()` or `FindFirstFile()` functions, or the VCL `FindFirst()` function (which uses `FindFirstFile()` internally.